# Is the following C++ singleton implementation?

Tags: c++, singleton, coding-style

I did see on internet some pattern for implementing singleton class as following:

```
class singleton {
public:
    int a;
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
    }
} singleton;

int main()
{
    // singleton b; COMPILATION ERROR
    singleton.a = 3;
    singleton.print();

    return 0;
}
```

It does compile on GCC but I got the feeling that naming the instance as the name of the class is not really a proper way to code.

- Is there any special rules which forbid such convention (instance name same as the class name)
- Is the source code compiling in other compiler ?

Comment: This is not on topic, but I consider a Singleton to be an extremely bad design pattern, to the point of thinking it's an anti-pattern: http://www.object-oriented-security.org/lets-argue/singletons

Comment: @Omni: You're not alone: http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the two question that you literally ask,

- yes, C++ has the notion of names of different kinds co-existing in the same scope, as in C, and
- yes, when the appropriate header is included the code compiles fine with MinGW g++ 4.4.1, Visual C++ 10.0, and Comeau Online 4.3.10.1.

When you're in doubt about whether some code snippet is standard-conforming, as a practical matter just submit it to [Comeau Online](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/).

That the code is technically OK does not, however, mean that it's OK... :-)

*Singleton* is used to describe something different than a *global variable*. What you have is a global variable. Ergo, it's not a singleton.

Two basic properties of a singleton are

- there is globally unique instance, and
- that instance is created lazily, on demand.

Usually one wants something *similar* to a global variable but more controlled. One wants a more controlled instantiation order, and the lazy creation helps with that. And one wants to limit the number of allowed instances, usually to

- just one single instance.

The latter is so common a reason for *using* singletons that e.g. [Wikipedia's article on singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) describes a singleton as "restricting the instantiation of a class to one object". But that's a simplistic view. Sometimes one needs a specific number of instances, as singletons. And e.g. for Python it's not uncommon to describe Python's `False` and `True` values as singletons of the `bool` type. And sometimes one needs a singleton (or singletons) while still allowing arbitrary instantiation.

In C++ one particularly easy way to implement a singleton is known as [*Meyers' Singleton*](http://www.google.no/search?q=meyers%27+singleton). Essentially the singleton instance is then a static variable within the function that provides access to it. This is usually combined with prohibiting general instantiation of the class, e.g. by the constructor or all constructors `private`, and the singleton access function a `static` member function.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: I disagree about the *that instance is created lazily, on demand*, while it's true that this is a common implementation this isn't a requirement of the pattern.

Answer (score 7):

```
class singleton ss;
```

You can construct more than one of these, so this is not a singleton.  And name hiding is arguably evil.  And singletons suck, so don't use them.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to resort to global state, a primary advantage of a singleton over a regular global variable is lazy loading... that is to say that the singleton object won't be instantiated until GetInstance() is called for the first time.

I don't like this implementation as it doesn't support lazy loading, and this, along with the lack of a single instance constraint (as John pointed out), defeats its purpose.

Comment: It's fairly easy to create lazily loaded globals too. No need to pollute your code with singletons for that.

Answer (score 3):

Hiding name in this way is definitely not a good idea. You will only confuse people who will see this code. [Wikipedia page for Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) contains implementation in different languages. You should have a look. And specially look into the drawback section. And this is not a true singleton as John Dibling pointed.